# Converting pdf's to images with Imagemagick + RMagic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm using paperclip at the moment to convert pdf files to images.

My code looks something like this

```
  def convert_keynote_to_slides
    system('convert -size 640x300 ' +  keynote.queued_for_write[:original].path + ' ' + KEYNOTE_PATH + '/' + File.basename( self.keynote_file_name )+"%02d.png")

    slide_basename = File.basename( self.keynote_file_name )

    files = Dir.entries(KEYNOTE_PATH).sort
    for file in files
      #puts file if file.include?(slide_basename +'-')
      self.slides.build("slide" => "#{file}") if file.include?(slide_basename)
    end

  end
```

I'm sure this can be re-factored to work better.

My questions are:

Is there a way to figure out the progress of ImageMagick if not how would I put this into a delayed job as im worried this wont scale very well.

Can anyone point me in the direction as to how to make this code better / more efficient. The KEYNOTE_PATH points to a directory in public where all of the images are held in a single folder im not sure if I like this or not. What would probably be better is to assign a random name to each file.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're doing extensive filtering of `keynote.queued_for_write[:original].path` and `File.basename( self.keynote_file_name )` input variables, so you're not susceptible to [shell meta-character injection attacks](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/78.html).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that its done my Paperclip I could be wrong however. I validate to make sure that the file is only a PDF.The path to the file is after it has been uploaded.